# Run shell using one shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have a requirement to create a shell to run other shells like below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
. ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File1
. ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File2
. ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File3
. ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File4
```

And in the DataLoad.sh which would have some "exit num" command in error handling.
But I want ALL this 4 command will be executed no matter which one encounter the "exit".
How can I do that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying

```
. scriptname ...
```

would cause the script to be executed in the current shell context.  This causes the main script to `exit` when any of the script does so.

Instead say:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ksh ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File1
ksh ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File2
ksh ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File3
ksh ${SCRIPT}/DataLoad.sh File4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't understood your question exactly, but i would suggest you to replace this script with find;

```
find -iname "file*" -exec DataLoad.sh {} ';'
```

Comment: if the first DataLoad.sh run to an "exit", will the next DataLoad.sh be run? Now once my DataLoad.sh run to an "exit", it will exit the whole shell and will not run the next one...

Comment: @Janus Only if `Dataload.sh` returns with a non-zero exit status. The answer from @devnull is preferred here.

Comment: it doesn't matter how first one exits, find run's them all